# DocumentDB Replace not Working

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I recently realized that DocumentDB supports stand alone update operations via ReplaceDocumentAsync.

I've replaced the Upsert operation below with the Replace operation.

```
var result = _client
    .UpsertDocumentAsync(_collectionUri, docObject)
    .Result;
```

So this is now:

```
var result = _client
    .ReplaceDocumentAsnyc(_collectionUri, docObject)
    .Result;
```

However, now I get the exception:

> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BadRequestException : ResourceType Document is unexpected.
>   ActivityId: b1b2fd71-3029-4d0d-bd5d-87d8d0a2fc95

No idea why, upsert and replace are of the same vein and the object is the same that worked for upsert, so I would expect it to work without problems.

All help appreciated.

Thanks

Update: Have tried to implement this using the SelfLink approach, and it works for Replace, but selflink does not work with Upsert. The behavior is quite confusing. I don't like that I have to build a self link in code using string concatenation.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that building the selflink with string concatenation is your only option here because `ReplaceDocument(...)` requires a link to the document. You show a link to the collection in your example. It won't suck the id out and find the document as you might wish.

The NPM module, [documentdb-utils](https://github.com/lmaccherone/documentdb-utils#getlink-getdoclink-getattachmentlink-and-getlinkarray), has library functions for building these links but it's just using string concatenation. I have seen an equivalent library for .NET but I can't remember where. Maybe it was in an Azure example or even in the SDK now.

Comment: What gets me is the discrepancy in behavior between Create / Replace / Upsert / and Delete. Methods with the same footprint and related names behave completely differently. Very disappointed by this.

Comment: You get used to it pretty fast. :-)

Comment: I'd say that this is actually intuitive.  In a create, you don't have a record in the db yet, and therefore, an `Id` isn't required to specify adequate information in order to perform the operation.  But an update needs a reference to the record you are trying to update/replace.  Therefore, you don't want to build a collection uri, but a document uri instead in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You can build a document link for a replace using the [UriFactory](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/blog/azure-documentdb-bids-fond-farewell-to-self-links/) helper class:

```
var result = _client
    .ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseId, collectionId, docObject.Id), docObject)
    .Result;
```

Unfortunately it's not very intuitive, as Larry has already pointed out, but a replace expects a document to already be there, while an upsert is what it says on the tin. Two different use-cases, I would say.

Answer (score 2):

In order to update a document, you need to provide the Collection Uri. If you provide the Document Uri it returns the following:

> ResourceType Document is unexpected.

Maybe the _collectionUri is a Document Uri, the assignment should look like this:

```
_collectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(DatabaseName, CollectionName);
```